# c# wmi ManagementEventWatcher.Options.Timeout issue

Tags: c#, wmi

The code uses the wmi component in semi-synchronous mode to monitor events on a remote computer.
Everything works correctly until the network connection between the client and the server is interrupted.
In this case the program remains frozen in the line:
ManagementBaseObject e = watcher.WaitForNextEvent ();
and the timeout does not work.
How can I manage the connection break correctly?
Thank you

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ConnectionOptions con1 = new ConnectionOptions();
  con1.Username = networkUser;
  con1.Password = networkPassword;
  con1.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
  con1.EnablePrivileges = true;
  con1.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
  ManagementPath mp1 = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + networkPath + @"\" + @"root\cimv2");
  try
  {
    string queryString =
         "SELECT * " +
         "FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " +
         "WITHIN  5 " +
         "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' ";

      WqlEventQuery wql = new WqlEventQuery(queryString);

      ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(mp1, con1);
      Scope.Connect();

      // create the watcher and start to listen
      ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
      watcher.Query = wql;
      watcher.Scope = Scope;

      watcher.Options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
      keepGoing = true;
      int nError = 0;
      while (keepGoing)
      {
        try
        {
          ManagementBaseObject e = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
          switch (e.ClassPath.ClassName)
          {
            case ("__InstanceDeletionEvent"):
              {
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
              }
            default:
              {
                Console.WriteLine("Evento non gestito : " + e.ClassPath.ClassName);
                break;
              }
          }
        }
        catch (System.Management.ManagementException e)
        {
          if (e.ErrorCode != ManagementStatus.Timedout)
            throw;
        }
      }
      watcher.Stop();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Errore: " + ex.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.
Setting the watcher timeout to:
watcher.Options.Timeout = new TimeSpan (0, 0, 0, 0, 1);